# Remove lines containing space in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, awk

Below is my comma separated input.txt file, i want to read the columns and write the lines in to the output.txt when any 1 column has a space.

Content of `input.txt`:

```
1,Hello,world
2,worl d,hell o
3,h e l l o, world
4,Hello_Hello,World@c#
5,Hello,W orld
```

Content of `output.txt`:

```
1,Hello,world
4,Hello_Hello,World@c#
```

is't possible to achieve using `awk`? Please help!

Comment: Why use `awk` when `grep -v` will do just fine ?

Comment: Updating the question with a game-changing additional requirement after you have received multiple substantial answers is not good form. I would be tempted to suggest to revert the edit, accept an answer, and post a new question.

Comment: ok reverted the chnages!

Comment: @H2CO3: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/is't

Comment: @minitech I know (seen Twitter?), but I still consider it a mistake. Seriously.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple way to filter out lines with spaces is using inverted matching with `grep`:

```
grep -v ' ' input.txt
```

If you *must* use `awk`:

```
awk '!/ /' input.txt
```

Or `perl`:

```
perl -ne '/ / || print' input.txt
```

Or pure `bash`:

```
while read line; do [[ $line == *' '* ]] || echo $line; done < input.txt
# or
while read line; do [[ $line =~ ' ' ]] || echo $line; done < input.txt
```

**UPDATE**

To check if let's say field 2 contains space, you could use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F, '$2 !~ / /' input.txt
```

To check if let's say field 2 OR field 3 contains space:

```
awk -F, '!($2 ~ / / || $3 ~ / /)' input.txt
```

**For your follow-up question in comments**

To do the same using `sed`, I only know these awkward solutions:

```
# remove lines if 2nd field contains space
sed -e '/^[^,]*,[^,]* /d' input.txt 
# remove lines if 2nd or 3rd field contains space
sed -e '/^[^,]*,[^,]* /d' -e '/^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]* /d' input.txt
```

**For your 2nd follow-up question in comments**

To disregard leading spaces in the 2nd or 3rd fields:

```
awk -F', *' '!($2 ~ / / || $3 ~ / /)' input.txt
# or perhaps what you really want is this:
awk -F', *' -v OFS=, '!($2 ~ / / || $3 ~ / /) { print $1, $2, $3 }' input.txt
```

Comment: You don't need { print } since it's the default action for awk.

Comment: Thanks @Jason for the `awk`. how to change the `awk` in order to check for one or two fields alone?

Comment: `awk -F, '$2 !~ / /'` this fails for `5,Hello,W orld`, since you only test for two fields, and there are more than `two`

Comment: Thanks @janos for the OR in awk. it is possible to write same command using sed? just curious

Comment: @janos this cmd '$2 !~ / /' is considering leading and trailing zero's also. anyways to remove them?

Answer (score 5):

This can also be done easily with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed '/ /d' input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is, i want to check for a particular column. I missed to add that in the Question.

Answer (score 3):

try this one-liner

```
awk 'NF==1' file
```

as @**jwpat7** pointed out, it won't give correct output if the line has only leading space, then this line, with regex should do, but it has been already posted in **janos's** answer.

```
awk '!/ /' file
```

or

```
awk -F' *' 'NF==1'
```

Comment: I would  +1 if this worked ... but it fails when the disqualifying spaces are at front of line

Comment: Pretty neat, but pretty obscure. Awk splits on whitespace and sets `NF` to the number of fields; if it is one, there was no whitespace to split on.

Comment: @jwpat7 you are correct, of course; but the OP's examples suggest this may not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash for the fun of it...

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    if [[ ! $line =~ " " ]]
    then
        echo $line
    fi
done < input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
columnWithSpace=2
ColumnBef=$(( ${columnWithSpace} - 1 ))

sed '/\([^,]*,\)\{${ColumnBef\}[^ ,]* [^,]*,/ d'
```

if you know the column directly (by example the 3):

```
sed '/\([^,]*,\)\{2}[^ ,]* [^,]*,/ d'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust the input to always have no more than three fields, simply finding a space somewhere after a comma is sufficient.

```
grep ',.* ' input.txt
```

If there can be (or usually are) more fields, you can pull that off with `grep -E` and a suitable [ERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended), but you are fast approaching the point at which the equivalent Awk solution will be more readable and maintainable.